# Finite pre-orders embeddable in the Rudin-Keisler ordering

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, posets, ultrafilters

$\DeclareMathOperator{\NPU}{\operatorname{NPU}}\DeclareMathOperator{\RK}{\,\mathrm{RK}}$A *pre-ordered* set is a pair $(P, \leq)$ where $P$ is a set and $\leq\subseteq P\times P$ is a reflexive and transitive relation.

Let $\NPU(\omega)$ be the set of non-principal ultrafilters on $\omega$. The *Rudin-Keisler pre-order* on $\NPU(\omega)$ is defined by
$${\cal U} \leq_{\RK} {\cal V} :\Leftrightarrow (\exists f:\omega\to\omega)(\forall U\in{\cal U}) f^{-1}(U)\in {\cal V} .$$

It is easy to see that $\leq_{\RK}$ is reflexive and transitive, but not anti-symmetric.

**Question.** Given a finite pre-ordered set $(P,\leq)$, is there a finite subset $S\subseteq\NPU(\omega)$ such that $(P,\leq)$ is isomorphic to $S$ with the pre-order inherited from $\text{NPU}(\omega)$?

Comment: There are incomparable ultrafilters, and since the product operation gives you upper bounds, one might hope to find a sufficiently independent family of ultrafilters, whose products make a copy of a finite Boolean algebra in the RK order. This would embed any partial order into the RK order. For pre-orders, you can easily handle clusters of equivalent nodes, since any nontrivial permutation of $\omega$ makes an isomorphic ultrafilter, which is RK equivalent but not equal. So my strategy is: find a strong antichain of ultrafilters, meaning incomparable products are RK incomparable.

Comment: In particular, I claim that to embed every finite preorder it suffices to embed every finite partial order.

Comment: I agree with @Joel's strategy, and I'll add that under CH (or weaker assumptions like cov(category)=c), there are lots of non-isomorphic selective ultrafilters, and these constitute what Joel calls a strong antichain.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the existence of an infinite strong antichain could be proved in ZFC, perhaps by an independent-sets argument.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Could you post an answer explaining why nonisomorphic selective ultrafilters necessarily form a strong antichain?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your interesting comments. @JoelDavidHamkins, do you have a hint why it is sufficient to consider finite partial orders?

Comment: RK equivalence is the same as isomorphism of the ultrafilters by a permutation of the underlying set. And so every ultrafilter is part of a huge cluster of continuum many equivalent ultrafilters. So once you embed a partial order, you can automatically make each cluster as big as you like and thereby have embedded a pre-order.

Comment: Now I get it - thanks @JoelDavidHamkins !

Comment: Under the assumption of Martin's Axiom for $\sigma$-centered partial orders the quotient algebra $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathit(fin}$ embeds in the Rudin-Keisler order of P-points, see  Raghavan and Shelah  _On embedding certain partial orders into the P-points under Rudin-Keisler and Tukey reducibility_  (https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2017-369-06/S0002-9947-2017-06943-9/)